# Having Trouble with ReactJS Links

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I started off thinking this was going to be an easy issue; however I was wrong.  I have the following home page:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = (props) =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>My Portal Home</h1>
      Click <Link to="/login">Here</Link> To Log In.
    </div>
  )
}
export default Home;
```

My main component looks like this:  I am certain it is NOT what it is supposed to look like:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './login/login';
import Home from './home/home';

const Main = (props) =>{
  return(
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

Finally my index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Main from "./main";
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I enter the site address, the home pages does not show and I get errors (warnings):

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component
    in Route (at main.js:11)
```

I am OBVIOUSLY doing this wrong, but my goal is to have a home page with a link to my login page.  Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your login component?

Comment: `Link` component missing on you first js .add `import {Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";` on first js home file

Comment: How have you exported the login component?

Comment: change the react dom import with like this `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom"; `  Missing router type
`

Comment: FYI you don't need to import {Component} in any of these files. These are all functional components. Only need to import Component when using "class ExampleClass extends Component {}" syntax.

Comment: for above comment check this link  https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rain-zosfn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';

const Main = () =>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>My Portal Home</h1>
      Click <Link to="/login">Here</Link> To Log In.
    </div>
  )
};
export default Home;
```

Login.js

```
import React from "react";

const Login = () =>{
  return(
    <div>
      Login
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

Comment: That does work, but not the result i wanted.  The login page is showing up under the home page.  I need the login page as it's own "app"

Comment: I figured it out! You need to add "exact" to <Route path="/" component={Home}/>. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Paddy.  Been pulling my hair out the past two hours trying to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Made a CodeSandbox, hopefully this helps

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-basic-2ylgv)

Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Main = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2> Home </h2>
  </div>
);

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    <h2> Login Page </h2>
  </div>
);

export default Main;
```

Comment: This is, essentially, where I started.  My home page will have a "Login" link which will call the login app. The home page is not supposed to be a SPA but a starting point for accessing the application.